# Setting layout in controller brings up error

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently trying to set up the controllers for multiple themes. For this I need yii to check the name of the app inside the folder rather than just pointing towards a folder I know the name of (users can generate themes, so It has to work this way). Each individual theme will have their own layout and views folders.

to get my login form working for each individual theme I had to use;

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $this->render('webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.site.index');
    }
```

This makes sense, it looks inside the themes and finds the views I need it to.

The issue I am having is that when I try to point the controller towards a specific layout, it brings up an error.

```
public $layout ='webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.layouts.column2';
```

How else would I do this? It works if I remove the Yii:App() bit from my code but how else will I get the generated names of the folders?

Thank you.

Edit. I changed my config to look at

```
layout'=>'webroot.themes.thetheme.views.layouts.main',
            'viewDir' => 'webroot.themes.thetheme.views', // the path to view files to use with this module.
            //'defaultLayout' => 'application.views.layouts.column2',
            'defaultLayout' => 'webroot.themes.thetheme.views.layouts.column2',
```

But still no luck.

Another edit.

I was able to get one page working by adding the first line to

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $this->layout = 'webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.layouts.main';
        $this->render('webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.site.index');
    }
```

But there has to be a better solution than doing this for every action, in every controller.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: EventController cannot find the requested view "/eventGroups/_view_3".

That's because the path to the dynamic folder can't be found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using themes you should do the following

```
Yii::app()->theme = Yii::app()->name;
$this->layout = '//layouts/main';
$this->render('index');
```

If you want to have this theme everywhere, the best way is to redeclare the init function of each controller

```
public function init(){
  parent::init();
  Yii::app()->theme = Yii::app()->name;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: Inside the actionIndex() function.
`public function actionIndex(){
  Yii::app()->theme = Yii::app()->name;
$this->layout = '//layouts/main';
$this->render('index');
}`

Comment: I'm still getting an error on finding this as there is a renderpartial in the venue. Or would I have to add this to every controller?

Comment: You should add it on every controller. The best way would be adding the Yii::app()->theme = Yii::app()->name; inside the controller init function. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that `Yii::app()->name` is not yet set during member initialization. This seems to be best way to do this

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $this->layout = 'webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.layouts.main';
    $this->render('webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.site.index');
}
```

You could also try to add constructor to avoid setting it in each action:

```
function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->layout = 'webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->name.'.views.layouts.main';
```

}

Comment: Would this still go in every controller?

Comment: If you want it on every controller you should make some base class with this constructor that you will derive from or add this constructor to every controller you want to have it in.

Comment: Working with some tweaks to pahs but the answer above worked like a charm. Point given anyway.